# in DOS how to SET /P with a string starting with spaces

Tags: batch-file, set, newline

I want to have this kind of result in a DOS batch:

```
==> Please enter your filename, formatted as
    [user][PC_id] :
```

allowing the user to enter the filename after the ":"

I tried a lot of combinations, but the best I can get it with

```
ECHO --^> Please enter your filename, formatted as
Set /P FILE=[user][PC_id] :
```

(blank spaces before "[" are not displayed)

Comment: You don't need to add your signature in the post - your user card is aded automatically for this purpose.

Comment: in DOS? you mean Windows, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have problems with a feature introduced in Vista/Win7.
It strips all whitespace characters in front of a string, when using `set/p`.

But in your case it's easy, as you want to echo two lines.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set LF=^


set /p "file=--> Please enter your filename, formatted as!LF!    [user][PC_id]"
```

Comment: actually, I just need spaces BEFORE my question.

I tried your answer : unfortunately, nothing is displayed on screen :-(

Comment: Do you have two empty lines after 'set LF=^'?

Comment: no difference with or without 'set LF=^', so no two empty lines. I work with MS Version 6.1.7601

Comment: WAIT!! I misunderstood your question. Your question was on my script & I understood it was concerning the resutl I had !! IT WORKS with two empty lines after 'SET LF=^' !!!! THANKS A LOT !

Answer (score 2):

jeb's solution works fine when you are printing 2 lines. But there is a generic solution that works when you only want to print a single line with leading space. All you need is a backspace character.

```
@echo off
setlocal
:: Define BS to contain a backspace
for /f %%A in ('"prompt $H&for %%B in (1) do rem"') do set "BS=%%A"

::Only need %BS% if you know prompt starts at line beginning
Set /P "FILE=%BS%    [user][PC_id] : "

::If prompt is not at line beginning then need an extra char before %BS%
<nul set /p "=Part1"
<nul set /p "=.%BS%    Part2"
```

Comment: I did not try yet your solution, but printing a backspace character was what I was trying to do by myself without succeeding (one of my many "lot of combinations") ;-) I might be interested in it one day or another, so, thank you for your help! ;)

Answer (score 2):

another variant:

```
exit | cmd /k prompt -$G Please enter your filename, formatted as$_$s$s$s[user][PC_id]$s
set /p FILE=

echo %FILE%
```