# Windows equivalent of "echo -n" no longer works in Win7

Tags: windows, cmd

I had a nifty trick in Windows `cmd.exe` (at least up to XP) to emulate the behaviour of the UNIX echo without a newline, `echo -n`. For example, the command:

```
<nul: set /p junk= xyzzy
```

would result in exactly six characters being output, the leading space and the string "xyzzy", and nothing else.

> If you're interested in *why* this works, it's actually an input command which outputs `" xyzzy"` as the prompt then waits for user input before assigning that input to the `junk` environment variable. In this particular case, it doesn't wait for user input since it grabs the input from the `nul` device.

It was rather useful in `cmd` scripts when (for example) processing files in a loop (one iteration per file) where you want to list more than one per line. By using this trick, you could simply output each file name followed by a space and no newline then, after the loop, output a newline to finish up:

```
Processing files:
    file1.txt file42.txt p0rn.zip
```

Now I discover that, under Windows 7, the spaces are no longer output so what I get is:

```
Processing files:
file1.txtfile42.txtp0rn.zip
```

Is there a way I can get `set /p` to start honouring my spaces again, or is there another way in Win7 to achieve the same effect?

I've tried quoting, using `.` (which works in `echo`) and even escaping the string with `^`, but none of them seem to work:

```
C:\Pax> <nul: set /p junk= xyzzy
xyzzy

C:\Pax> <nul: set /p junk=" xyzzy"
xyzzy

C:\Pax> <nul: set /p junk=' xyzzy'
' xyzzy'

C:\Pax> <nul: set /p junk=. xyzzy
. xyzzy

C:\Pax> <nul: set /p junk=^ xyzzy
xyzzy
```

What I need is:

```
C:\Pax> some_magical_command_with_an_argument xyzzy
 xyzzy
```

which will give me the space(s) at the start *and* no newline at the end.

Comment: +1 for trying REALLY hard to do things in Batch files that any SANE person would be doing in PERL or PYTHON.

Comment: @Warren, unfortunately policy dictates we can use only what is available on a basic Win install. So Perl and Python are out, despite the fact I could probably do it in half a line of code :-) I _could_ rewrite the scripts in VBScript but I'm hoping for an easier fix - the scripts aren't small. Having said that, I could possibly just do the echoing bit in VBS so I may look into that. If you put that in an answer, I'll +1 you, since it was your comment on using a decent language that got me thinking that way.

Comment: So your company doesn't let people install software using an installer? :-)

Comment: @Warren: not quite, _we_ can install anything we want as long as it's approved by legal and kept off the main network. However, this is a script sent to customers who would likely baulk at having to install Python/Perl.

Comment: Even microsoft "FixIts" are EXEs. Just build a small EXE. You do know how to do that?

Comment: @Warren, that's an answer, not a comment. Nudge, nudge, wink, wink :-)

Comment: This issue [has already been raised](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13488592/in-dos-how-to-set-p-with-a-string-starting-with-spaces "in DOS how to SET /P with a string starting with spaces") actually. I guess part of the answer to *your* question would be "No simple (i.e. single command) solution in batch".

Comment: @Warren P: WHY are you YELLING RANDOM WORDS and NAMES in ALL CAPS?

Comment: It seems like the thing to do when talking about DOS BATCH FILES. :-)

Comment: @WarrenP: For emphasis, *italics* or **bold** would seem to me more conventional than ALL CAPS, even though not as convenient.

Comment: Point taken. *How do you do italics in a comment?* Oh look I figured it out.

Comment: Wow, I was just about to suggest JScript and then I scrolled down lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't using `set` or other `cmd`-internal stuff, but you can use `cscript` (also included in a standard Windows install) to do a similar thing. You can even control it from the `cmd` file itself (no separate files to maintain) by use of creating temporary `vbs` files.

Place this code in your `cmd` file:

```
rem Create the VBS file to output spaces and a word.

echo.for i = 1 to WScript.Arguments.Item(0) >spacetext.vbs
echo.     WScript.StdOut.Write ^" ^" >>spacetext.vbs
echo.next >>spacetext.vbs
echo.WScript.StdOut.Write WScript.Arguments.Item(1) >>spacetext.vbs

rem Do this once per word you want output (eg, in a loop).

cscript /nologo spacetext.vbs 0 Hello,
cscript /nologo spacetext.vbs 1 my
cscript /nologo spacetext.vbs 1 name
cscript /nologo spacetext.vbs 1 is
cscript /nologo spacetext.vbs 4 Pax.

rem Do this at the end to add newline and kill temp file.

echo.
del spacetext.vbs
```

The output of this is what you would expect:

```
Hello, my name is    Pax.
```

Answer (score 1):

This is very similar to paxdiablo's answer, except I use a hybrid JScript/batch file instead of a temporary VBScript file.

My script is called `jEval.bat` - and it simply evaluates any valid JScript expression and writes the result to stdout, optionally with a trailing newline. The silly little script is extremely useful for batch programming.

Assuming `jEval.bat` is either in your current folder, or somewhere in your PATH, then you can simply do something like:

```
call jeval "' xyzzy'"
```

Here is the script. It really is very simple. Most of the code is related to documentation, error handling, and a built in help system.

```
@if (@X)==(@Y) @end /* harmless hybrid line that begins a JScrpt comment

::************ Documentation ***********
:::
:::jEval  JScriptExpression  [/N]
:::jEval  /?
:::
:::  Evaluates a JScript expression and writes the result to stdout.
:::
:::  A newline (CR/LF) is not appended to the result unless the /N
:::  option is used.
:::
:::  The JScript expression should be enclosed in double quotes.
:::
:::  JScript string literals within the expression should be enclosed
:::  in single quotes.
:::
:::  Example:
:::
:::    call jEval "'5/4 = ' + 5/4"
:::
:::  Output:
:::
:::    5/4 = 1.25
:::

::************ Batch portion ***********
@echo off

if "%~1" equ "" (
  call :err "Insufficient arguments"
  exit /b
)
if "%~2" neq "" if /i "%~2" neq "/N" (
  call :err "Invalid option"
  exit /b
)
if "%~1" equ "/?" (
  setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
  for /f "delims=" %%A in ('findstr "^:::" "%~f0"') do (
    set "ln=%%A"
    echo(!ln:~3!
  )
  exit /b
)
cscript //E:JScript //nologo "%~f0" %*
exit /b

:err
>&2 echo ERROR: %~1. Use jeval /? to get help.
exit /b 1


************ JScript portion ***********/
if (WScript.Arguments.Named.Exists("n")) {
  WScript.StdOut.WriteLine(eval(WScript.Arguments.Unnamed(0)));
} else {
  WScript.StdOut.Write(eval(WScript.Arguments.Unnamed(0)));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, have the right answer now: you can't have a leading `<space>` in Win7 with `set /p`. There are differences between Windows versions:

```
Syntax                |  XP                                 |  Vista and Windows 7
----------------------+-------------------------------------+-------------------------------------
<nul set /p =!msg!    |- If 1st char is quote, then trims   |- Trims leading white space chars.   
       or             |  that quote, and if at least one    |- If 1st non white space char is     
<nul set /p "=!msg!"  |  additional quote, than trims last  |  quote, then that quote is treated  
                      |  quote and all remaining chars.     |  as white space and trimmed, and if
                      |- If 1st non trimmed char is =, then |  at least one additional quote, then
                      |  syntax error.                      |  trims last quote and all remaining
                      |                                     |  chars.
                      |                                     |- If 1st non trimmed char is =, then
                      |                                     |  syntax error.
----------------------+-------------------------------------+-------------------------------------
<nul set /p ="!msg!"  |- Trims leading control chars and    |- Trims leading white space chars.
       or             |  spaces.                            |- If 1st non trimmed char is =, then 
<nul set /p "="!msg!""|- If 1st non trimmed char is =, then |  syntax error.
                      |  syntax error.                      |
----------------------+-------------------------------------+-------------------------------------

On Vista and Windows 7, the trimmed leading white space chars are:
    9  0x09  Horizontal Tab
   10  0x0A  New Line
   11  0x0B  Vertical Tab
   12  0x0C  Form Feed
   13  0x0D  Carriage Return
   32  0x20  Space
  255  0xFF  Non-breaking Space
```

[source](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=23501#p23501)

For an other technique to get leading spaces in pure batch see [here](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4213)

Answer (score 0):

You mean like this?

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
FOR /l %%i IN (1,1,4) DO <NUL SET /p var="item %%i "
```

Result:

item 1 item 2 item 3 item 4

Or do you absolutely insist on a space at the start?